# What is the difference between plugins and dependencies in the Vue.js UI?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

When using the ui you have the option of installing dependencies and plugins.

I am confused about the difference between both of these.

For instance, I can install axios as a dependency and a plugin.

Do I need to do both? Why do one over the other?

My current understanding is that dependency is just that, it adds a package to your project while a plugin will add configuration as well.

Am I correct in thinking that?

Comment: You can, in general, say that plugin is a type of dependency. A dependency doesn't have to be a plugin, but a plugin surely means that your code _depends_ on it. "Plugin" is a way to to use the dependency, while a dependency is simply "anything that your code depends on".

Comment: For vue it would be more accurate to say that a plugin is a script, and a dependency is a library

Answer (score 8):

A plugin is exactly what you described. It 'plugs into' another piece of software and adds functionality. A dependency on the other hand means that your software simply depends on something to function correctly - usually code.

In your axios example:

The axios plugin installs another prototype property on your Vue instance (`this.$axios`.. or whatever it is called) so it definitely adds a feature to Vue.

You could also only use Axios by itself and import it in the files you need
`import axios from 'axios'`. You don't add any feature to Vue itself - you just use another software within your app. Axios here is a dependency.

Answer (score 7):

I will probably not be completely correct, but my understanding is

## Plugins vs Dependencies

### Command line

- **dependencies** are installed via the command line as `npm install <name>` or `npm install --save <name>` to add the dependency to package.json
- **plugins** are installed via the command line as `vue add @scope/vue-cli-plugin-<name>` or with the shorthand `vue add @scope/<name>`

### Installation

- **dependencies** are placed into your projects node_modules folder
- **plugins** will invoke the generator.js script of the plugin being installed. This generator.js may add dependencies to package.json, add import statements to files in your project, add/alter existing components, or any of the various things listed under the [generator api docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/dev-guide/generator-api.html#generator-api)

### Usage

- **dependencies** will need to be imported into any file you use them in, or imported globally, before they are able to be used
- **plugins** often will have already set up global imports, making them available in every file. Plugins will also often add additional scripts to package.json (which show up as tasks in the vue ui)